# Google DrEdit example for Java won't work

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I followed the steps to deploy DrEdit for Java:

https://github.com/googledrive/dredit/tree/master/java

When I visit the app, I get this error in the AppEngine log console!

```
2013-10-02 12:51:08.404
/start
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.drive.samples.dredit.DrEditServlet.loginIfRequired(DrEditServlet.java:149)
    at com.google.drive.samples.dredit.StartPageServlet.doGet(StartPageServlet.java:46)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
```

This is line 149. credentialManager is null.

```
protected void loginIfRequired(HttpServletRequest req,
    HttpServletResponse resp) {
  Credential credential = getCredential(req, resp);
  if (credential == null) {
    // redirect to authorization url
    try {
      resp.sendRedirect(credentialManager.getAuthorizationUrl());  // line 149
```

It's supposed to be set in init()

```
  public void init() throws ServletException {
    super.init();
    // init credential manager
    credentialManager = new CredentialManager(
        getClientSecrets(), TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY);
  }
```

I was unable to use System.out.println because it would never display in the logs, even though I selected "All Requests".

I'm also getting NoSuchMethodError:

```
Error for /
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets.load(Lcom/google/api/client/json/JsonFactory;Ljava/io/InputStream;)Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleClientSecrets;
    at com.google.drive.samples.dredit.DrEditServlet.getClientSecrets(DrEditServlet.java:249)
    at com.google.drive.samples.dredit.DrEditServlet.init(DrEditServlet.java:88)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
```

This happens to be the line:

```
249       return GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, stream);
```

I should mention that it works ok locally when I visit localhost:8888/start, in that it just sends me to Google to authenticate, but of course fails when it tries to redirect to the appspot.com/oauth2callback.

Answer (score 1):

The "NoSuchMethodError" is probably a mismatch between the code you have copy/pasted and the version of the Google Oauth library that you have installed. My guess would be that the library was updated, but Google didn't go back and update the DrEdit example. If you're using Eclipse with the Google plugin it will get the latest libs for you.

On your last point, to test oauth on your local server, there are a couple of tricks.

**Option 1.** Create an entry in your local /etc/hosts file (or equivalent) `127.0.0.1 dev.example.com`. You can then configure dev.example.com as a callback URL in the API console.

**Option 2.** Use goo.gl to create a shortened URL for localhost:8000/mycallbackservlet  You can then configure the shortened URL as a callback URL in the API console. (NB, I use option 1, so haven't tried this personally).

In both cases, you will need to modify your code to sense it's running on the local devserver and adjust its callback URL accordingly.

On your NPE question, clearly it's hard to say without further information, but my 2c is  DrEdit is not a good entry point to understanding oauth.

hth

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I am also working on DrEdit code and I have been through the error as no such method for line -
return GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, stream);

I corrected the code by adding one line before this statement as -

```
InputStream stream = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE_PATH);
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream); //I have added this line.
try {
      return GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, reader); //initially it was stream. I changed it to reader.
```

This solves my no such method problem. I am not sure about the NPE that you are getting. Hope this small correction, also resolves your problem.